# Template file not loading for block view

Tags: views, theming

I have a block view in the header. The suggested tpl files are block__mens_header (block--mens-header.tpl) as well as node--mens-header.tpl For some reason the more general tpl files are working but I need to get specific here. Is there a preprocess function I need before these will be seen?

Comment: Got node--mens-header.tpl to work but the block still isn't...?

Comment: Did you configured the block visibility setting to appear in some specific page(s)? Did you try to clear your cache as well?

Comment: The block is visible and i did clear the cache plenty of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember, in drupal 6 at least, that you need to have block.tpl.php there, even if you don't modify it at all, in order for the specific block templates to be seen.

ADD:  If it's in there, you might try a preprocess_block() hook with something like:

```
$variables['template_files'][] = 'block--mens-header';
```

stuck in it.  This should point it to block--mens-header.tpl.php in your theme directory.  Obviously, wrap that in some logic so it's only set for the block in question.

Comment: I do have the block.tpl file in the dir. Not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: is this for drupal 7 or 6? I am using 7. Also can't say I know much PHP so what logic do I need...? Is there documentation I can read on this? I am trying to learn.Thanks

Comment: I don't know enough about d7 to rattle something off right here.  I'd suggest digging through drupal.org's documentation (A good start is http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7 ) or grab a good book.  It's pretty straightforward, but also complex, all wrapped up in one :)

Comment: oh...and make sure you clear your caches often....